# Find in text and make a warning window

Tags: powershell, search, ini

I want to search in the text of an INI file for paths that are like `C:\example\example`. When it find a path like this I want that a message box with a warning is displayed on the screen. The INI files are in a folder and his subfolders.

I tried but I failed.

```
$PathOfFolderAndSubfolder = C:\example\example\*
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $PathOfFolderAndSubfolder -Filder \*/) -eq $true) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("error", "error", 0)
}
```

Comment: This makes absoluetly no sense. Could you please rephrase your question? Where is your ini file in the code? Please post the errors that you get. And check for correct spelling in your code (`-Filder` ?). And enclose the value for  `$PathOfFolderAndSubfolder` in quotes

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ChildItem` is for enumerating the child items of containers (e.g. files in directories), not for listing the content of files. Use `Get-Content` for the latter:

```
$filename = 'C:\path\to\some.ini'
$pattern  = 'C:\example\example'

if ((Get-Content $filename) -like "*${pattern}*") {
    [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("error", "error", 0)
}
```

If you want to check every INI file in a particular folder (sub)tree you need to recurse into the folder and check each matching file, e.g. like this:

```
$basedir  = 'C:\some\folder'
$filename = 'C:\path\to\some.ini'
$pattern  = 'C:\example\example'

$found = Get-ChildItem $basedir -Include '*.ini' -Recurse |
         Where-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName) -like "*${pattern}*" }

if ($found) {
    [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("error", "error", 0)
}
```

Comment: thanks thats working. Is there any way that i can set the parth of the ini file with the error in the message box?

Comment: ``($found | Select-Object -Expand FullName) -join "`r`n"``